# Wildfly 12 infinispan cache lookup is not working

Tags: wildfly, java-9, infinispan, java-10

I'm migration from wildfly 10 to wildfly 12. I have created local cache same as configured in wildfly 10.

standalone-full.xml configuration:

```
 <cache-container name="DataCache" default-cache="modelcache" statistics-enabled="false">
            <local-cache name="modelcache" statistics-enabled="false"/>
        </cache-container>
```

Lookup code in singleton ejb annotated with @startup:

```
 @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/DataCache")
private CacheContainer Container;
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Container.start();
    modelCache = Container.getCache("modelcache");
```

}

I'm getting the below exception while deploying file

Caused by:

> org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000436: Cache 'modelcache' has been requested, but no cache configuration exists
> with that name and no default cache has been set for this container

How to fix this?

Comment: How are you starting WildFly?

Comment: standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0 -c standalone-full.xml

Comment: Please show the stack trace

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>infinispan/DataCache</res-ref-name>
    <lookup-name>java:jboss/infinispan/cache/DataCache/modelcache</lookup-name>
</resource-ref>
```

in `jboss-web.xml`. When requesting the cache do it like this (note that the `name` annotation property is used to specify the resource):

```
@Resource(name = "infinispan/DataCache")
private Cache<K, V> cache;
```

See this thread for more details: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/277425

Answer (score 1):

Put the following entry in your project descriptor file (web.xml, ejb-jar.xml, etc)

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>infinispan/DataCache</res-ref-name>
    <lookup-name>java:jboss/infinispan/container/DataCache</lookup-name>
</resource-ref>
```

Answer (score 0):

For wildfly 10 you can lookup your infinispan cache or cache container in the following way

1. You need to define your cache in standalone-ha.xml(High availability) under the following subsystem

```
 <cache-container name="myCacheContainer" default-cache="myCache" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
              <replicated-cache name="myCache">
                    <expiration lifespan="86400000" max-idle="3600000"/>
                </replicated-cache>
                </cache-container>
```

2. Once you have defined the cache you can lookup either the cache or the container.
   2.a To lookup the cache you should setup a resource ref element in your project
   descriptor file i.e (web.xml,jboss-web.xml etc.)

   infinispan/myCache
    java:jboss/infinispan/cache/myCacheContainer/myCache

   2.b If you want to  lookup cache container instead you also need to define configuration lookup in your project descriptor. So resource ref looks like this

   ```
    <resource-ref>
   ```

   infinispan/myCacheContainer
   org.infinispan.manager.CacheContainer
   java:jboss/infinispan/container/myCacheContainer


   infinispan/myCache-config
   org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration
   java:jboss/infinispan/configuration/myCacheContainer/default
3. Now if using spring you can do a JNDI lookup for cache like this

   ```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="myCache"
   ```

   jndi-name="infinispan/myCache" />

   3.a Or you can lookup the container like this

   <jee:jndi-lookup id="myCacheContainer"
   jndi-name="infinispan/myCacheContainer" />
4. Now  you can inject the cache like the following

   @Resource(name="myCache")
   private Cache cache;

   4.a You can inject the container like the following

   @Resource(name="myCacheContainer")
   private CacheContainer cacheContainer;

Comment: Had hell formatting xml on stackoverflow.  Half of my xml is lost.